# BreezeJS with .NET System.Services.Data.DataService OData Server: HTTP OPTIONS not supported for $metadata

Tags: odata, breeze, wcf-data-services

I am trying to use BreezeJS with an existing OData server, that was implemented using .NET System.Services.Data.DataService, Version 4.0. As it seems, BreezeJS is doing a http OPTIONS request to get $metadata, but the server throws a NotImplemented exception. 
When I manually request $metadata using http GET in the browser, I am getting (XML formatted) metadata fine.

Is there a way to configure Breeze to use http GET or would I need to somehow adjust the server to support http OPTIONS?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The OPTIONS request is part of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8342739).  You need to configure your server to support [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), or don't use cross-origin requests from the browser.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19843014/2517406) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26163426/2517406) regarding using WCF with CORS.  It seems the recommendation is to switch to Web API.

Comment: This seems to be correct, but confuses me. Breeze claims to support OData V1/V2 ("odata"), V3 ("webApiOData") as well as V4 ("webApiOdata4", preliminary, but the docs may be outdated) with different adapters. The links seem to indicate that Breeze does not work with V1/V2 (WCF DataServices) due to the lack of CORS support, which can only be achieved by moving to Web API. This may be a limitation of either datajs and/or Odata on the server side, though.

Comment: The support for CORS needs to come on the server side.  Do you need CORS support in your application?

Comment: I was not even aware of CORS until this matter came up. The server is an existing software, running as a Windows service and providing odata on a given port. The angular/breeze client for now is being developed and test-driven using lite-server, obviously on a different port, but on the same machine. Any hints whether changing settings would somehow recolve the issue?

Comment: Obviously the simple solution is to run everything on the same port.  If you can't do that, maybe you could have a passthrough service on your web server that basically proxies requests through to the odata service.  To the browser, it would look like all requests are going to the same place.